# How to autoresize text with NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nsattributedstring, autoresize

I have a button which opens a dropdown menu.
so, inside the button i have a text and a font awesome icon (down arrow)

i used attributed string to set the text and the icon separately. (had problems with the text being truncated)

now it looks fine, but i need to provide the font size as part of the attributes.
i want the font to auto resize  - if the screen is larger and the button gets bigger - so should the text.

this is the attribute string part

```
    let iconPart = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\u{F107}", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "fontello", size: 23)!])

    let textPart = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Category  ", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Gotham", size: 19)!])
```

i've seen this solution:

```
    let systemDynamicFontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .subheadline)
    let size = systemDynamicFontDescriptor.pointSize
    let font = UIFont(name: "Gotham", size: size)
```

but this seems to keep the font size fixed according to the text style (.subheadline in this example)

is there a way of doing it?